# generate apk file using android maven plugin

Tags: android-maven-plugin

`I am trying to generate apk file using maven,my android project has dependency with app compact-v7 and google play services.I am using android 4.4.2.can you please show me pom.xml file to generate apk with these dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example projects https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/ and the some of the documentation.

Also look at the Maven Android SDK Deployer